# how to compile protobuf message implement Parcelable with android studio protobuf plugin?

Tags: android, plugins, protocol-buffers, parcelable, protoc

there was cmdline options to generate message implement parcelable like this:

protoc --javanano_out=optional_field_style=accessors,parcelable_messages=true:d:\ ./message.proto

how to do this with android studio protobuf plugin?

Answer (score 2):

try add

```
option 'optional_field_style=accessors'
option 'parcelable_messages=true'
```

in your

```
javanano{/*add here*/}
```

Comment: I'm using protobuf-lite and I put the options in my `javalite{}`, but it doesn't work. So what should I do?

Comment: Parcelable support of java/javalite compiler not found yet, seems that only javanano compiler support parcelable code gen.
Hope for impl for java or javalite .
any news?